# How to combine the multiple rows data in single resultant record in Oracle?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

We have below plain result to start with for DBT_C_MT_MSG_DET

```
PROD_REF_ID SUB_FLD TAG_NO  TAG_VAL_1

GF41800427  1       32A     24-Oct-2018
GF41800427  2       32A     SGD
GF41800427  3       32A     7829.43
```

By combining it with other tables and conditions and all, I need to put the TAG_VAL_1 one after another for perticular PROD_REF_ID, based on SUB_FLD value.

Desired result :

```
PROD_REF_ID TAG_NO  Date            Currency    Amount

GF41800427  32A     24-Oct-2018     SGD         7829.43
```

I tried with below as a part of select but then I get 3 records with other two as null :

```
  case when sub_fld = 1 then tag_val_1 end as tag32A_Date,
  case when sub_fld = 2 then tag_val_1 end as tag32A_Curr,
  case when sub_fld = 3 then tag_val_1 end as tag32A_Amt,
```

unexpected result :

```
TAG32A_DATE     TAG32A_CURR     TAG32A_AMT  PROD_REF_ID

24-Oct-2018                                 GF41800427  
                SGD                         GF41800427  
                                7829.43     GF41800427
```

Pls suggest.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use aggregate function like max() or min()

```
select PROD_REF_ID,
max(case when sub_fld = 1 then tag_val_1 end) as tag32A_Date,
max(case when sub_fld = 2 then tag_val_1 end) as tag32A_Curr,
max(case when sub_fld = 3 then tag_val_1 end) as tag32A_Amt
from tablename 
group by PROD_REF_ID
```